# Most efficient way of writing a (To File) logger in PHP?

Tags: php, logging

Hopefully someone here can help me out - basically I have a logging class that I'm updating (Made it ages ago), and I want to make sure it logs messages under 98-99% of circumstances. However right now it doesn't handle exit()s, it basically just writes to a file (Opening, writing, and closing) every time a message/error is sent to the logger.

What would be the best way to handle exit()s, and be efficient in terms of disk writes? Right now I'm looking at __destruct in the logger class (With fopen, fwrite, and fclose being called in it), however I'm not quite sure if this is safe, or efficient.

Edit: What about set_error_handler()? I remember reading years ago that this was very slow and not very good for custom errors/messages (Like SQL issues)

Comment: So the question is how to invoke your logger if you use `exit()` or `die()` in your script?

Comment: It might also be an idea to consider `file_put_contents()` rather than `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()`.

Comment: Sean's answer is what you're looking for. Implementing the `register_shutdown_function` should help you out without requiring to change much of the code.

Comment: Additional resources: http://www.nyphp.org/PHundamentals/7_PHP-Error-Handling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to log something when your script ends, you should take a look at PHP's `register_shutdown_function()`:

```
function shutdown()
{
     // .. log code here.
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

You should avoid using the `__destruct()` method as there is no guarantee that it will be called when you expect it to be called.

You could also take a look at PHP's built in `error_log()` method to write the contents to the actual PHP error log file (this is possibly more reliable than writing your own logger).

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: As well as this, for the efficiency, open the file once in the constructor, perform your writes as needed, and close the file in the shutdown function.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll use register_shutdown_function inside a class, called in the __construct of it. That way it only needs to be loaded to be called, and is safer than __destruct.

Answer (score 1):

I always use some global function, e.g.

```
function BeforeExit () {
  //do stuff like logging
  exit;
}
```

Comment: I use the same "construct" before header(), die(), etc. to save session data, set (new) cookie data, do logging, do benchmarking and other stuff.